# React native Modal bypasses expo navigation bar setting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

In my App.js i have set :

```
import * as NavigationBar from "expo-navigation-bar";

...In my component

 useEffect(() => {
    if (android) {
      NavigationBar.setBackgroundColorAsync("transparent");
    }
  }, []);
```

which sets my navigation bars transparent in all screens,but when a modal is visible :

```
    <Modal
      animationType="none"
      transparent
      visible={isVisible}
      presentationStyle="overFullScreen"
      hardwareAccelerated
    >
```

...navigation bar becomes white,even when i try to set it also within my modal component as well,any known solutions for this ?

Comment: What are you using the modal for? Maybe there's another approach you could use? I had endless trouble using the built in modals.

Comment: Hi. would you share some alternative ideas ?

Comment: What are you presenting in the modal? We were able to replace ours with [react-native-dialog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dialog)

Comment: Is it the same with transparent={false} and without presentationStyle ?

Comment: @SiddharthMishra yes nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Android as well. What I believe is happening is the react-native modal is simply taking the default `android:navigationBarColor` in the styles.xml and so every time it pops up, it overwrites the current navigation bar color until it gets dismissed.

The flag statusBarTranslucent did not work for me.

I was able to fix this by navigating to `/res/values/styles.xml` in your `app` or `src` folder
It really helps if you change your view style to "Android"

[image: Android Project View]

then

[image: Styles xml]

Then in the AppTheme style I added navigationBarColor to be transparent.
It looks like this

```xml
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item> // <----This is what I added
  </style>
```

Then in my react native code, I used `react-native-navigation-bar-color`. I believe this should work with `expo-navigation-bar` since the main issue is derived from react native modal trying to overlay the default navBarColor value.

```js
import changeNavigationBarColor from "react-native-navigation-bar-color";

  const setDarkMode = (isDarkMode: boolean) => {
    // logic to change my app's themeProvider to dark mode
    changeNavigationBarColor(isDarkMode ? "black" : "white"); // Then I change the navigation bar color.
  };
```

Hopefully this helps someone!

Comment: Thanks for answering,how would i navigate to res/values/styles.xml? i have no experience in modifying native modules

Comment: I've updated my answer above with a photo of how to find res/values in Android studio. You can also use VS Code and find this file by hitting CMD/Ctrl + P and typing "styles", but if you already have android studio I'd recommend using it to avoid typos

Comment: The solution you gave might work for React Native CLI but I think the question was related to Expo Workflow as the package being used is expo-navigation-bar